# php mysql query - output value of variable in the query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query in php:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '%details%'");
```

However I want the query to be dynamic by changing the `LIKE` section of the query. Instead of:

```
LIKE '%details%'
```

I want to put a variable in there:

```
LIKE '% $format %'
```

where $format is a string.

Everything I have tried thus far has failed.

Whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: There are plenty of ways of doing this, but the right way is to use parameterized queries. Remember little Bobby Tables...  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Here's a great question on topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping in braces:

```
LIKE '%{$format}%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using double quotes you could simply do:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '%$format%'");
```

Or simply concatenate the string:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '%" . $format . "%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is already in double quotes, so just surround your variable with curly braces and you should be good to go.

```
"SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '%{$format}%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Before passing the variable do this

```
$format = '%' . $format . '%';
now simply put it in the query.

$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '$format'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer. I can do it exactly like you want.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata' AND meta_value LIKE '%$details%'");
```

<sub>Since the query is wrapped in double quotes, you dont need to escape anything.</sub>